# Xamarin 4.1.1.3 install fails requiring Build Tools that are already installed

Tags: xamarin

I have VS Community 2015 installed on a Windows 7 machine.
Few days ago new Xamarin version, the 4.1.1.3 one, has been released.
I have tried to install it (upgrading from 4.1.0.350) many times but every time I receive message about Build Tools requirement, even if the Build Tools 2013 and 2015 are correctly installed on the machine.

I have tried to reinstall Build Tools, repair VS and actual Xamarin installation without any success.

What may I check to be able to upgrade?
Thanks in advance for any help I will receive.

Comment: I have similar issue.  The error message appears right after copying files.  Any way to see what the error is?  The error popup is generic and asks to contact vendor.

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure if you were lucky enough to find a solution yet.

I faced a similar issue and was able to overcome it by :

**1)First running the VS as Administrator.**

**2)Then Follow the normal update process Via Tools -> Options -> Xamarin -> Other**

You will be asked to close VS during installation which is OK.

I guess that means the update process needs to access some files which require Admin rights? anyway it worked for me and I hope it works for you as well.

All the best!.

Br,
Khalid